# unset session variable those start with cart

Tags: php, session, cart

i have a session variables with name

> $_session['cart_10'], $_session['cart_2'], $_session['cart_8'], $_session['cart_110'], $_session['city'], $_session['location'], $_session['store_id']

now i want to unset all session variable that start with 'cart' like following session variable

> $_session['cart_10'], $_session['cart_2'], $_session['cart_8'], $_session['cart_110']

please help me to solve that problem

Comment: You should have used an array. Your current $_SESSION variable list now requires comparing the keys in a loop (probably like the rest of your code). Did you write something specific that didn't work?

Comment: can u write a loop code for unset session variable those start with 'cart'

Comment: Please write it yourself or hire a developer. Show a little effort, put in what you have tried.

Comment: You should use a separate array for your cart contents like `$_SESSION['cart'] = array()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this function

```
function unsetcart($a)
{
    foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v)
    {
        if(substr($k, 0, strlen($a))==$a)
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$k]);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

unsetcart('cart_');
```

Comment: thanxxxxxx varun your code working so good.. some people said hire a developer. if i want to hire a developer so why stakeoverflow is here..

Comment: @boyrock75 stackoverflow is not here to give you code for free its here to help you fix and make your CODE work, Varun was kind enough to help you as this was a rather simple thing but do not expect people to always do that for you, normally your question would have been closed before any answers would be posted.

Comment: @VarunVictor probably easier and better if you use `if (strpos($k, $a) === 0)` instead of `if(substr($k, 0, strlen($a))==$a)`